# Variable overriding in LESS when using @import (reference) not working. Why?

Tags: css, less

I want to do the variable overriding thing in LESS ([solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350779/bootstrap-variable-overriding-with-less)) but I need to import a resource by reference and it does not work.

**file one.less:**

```
@color: #ffffff;
.foo { color: @color; }
```

**file two.less:**

```
// file two.less
.bar {
  @import (reference) 'one.less';
}
@color: #000000;
```

**The output:**

```
.bar .foo {
  color: #ffffff // <-- expected: "color: #000000"
}
```

I could not find anything about that in the internet.

Is it a bug (working with version 1.7.5)? Is it a leak in my head? Or is it simply not supported?

Comment: If I am correct there is a scope problem, the import happens within `.bar` and so the `color` from the imported file takes precedence over the `color` defined outside `.bar` in global scope. Have you tried declaring the `color` after the `import`?

Comment: Thank you - idiot me. That's it for the example.
But that does not help me for my real-life code, because I have a lot of nested @import (reference) ("one.less" has an import to another file that has another import to another file etc.) and I do want to set all variables of all files in the root-less file.

Comment: The only solution I found was to reimport things and override it then.

Comment: I am not aware of your exact use-case, but can you not create a separate file just for the variables alone and import it in global scope?