# Navigation collapse button not working for iPad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Working everywhere else except *iPad*s, view port also added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Please help me find a solution, see [my website](http://allvideolectures.com).

Here is how the result is viewed on [iPhone](http://mobt.me/BK8T).

Here is how the result is viewed on [iPad](http://mobt.me/BK8p).

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="container topmenu">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" style="margin-top: -1px;">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/allvideolecturescom/320909451432640" class="soc">
                    <img src="http://allvideolectures.com/img/facebook_top.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/videolecture" class="soc">
                    <img src="http://allvideolectures.com/img/twitter_top.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="https:/google.com/+Allvideolectures" class="soc">
                    <img src="http://allvideolectures.com/img/google_top.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://allvideolectures.com/">
        <img src="http://allvideolectures.com/img/logo.png" alt="all video lectures let's learn" /><span class="logoleft">ALLVIDEO</span><span class="logoright">LECTURES.COM</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse mainmenu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="http://allvideolectures.com/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="http://allvideolectures.com/courses">Courses</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="http://allvideolectures.com/blog">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="http://allvideolectures.com/aboutus">About</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="http://allvideolectures.com/contactus">Contact us</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <form method="get" action="http://allvideolectures.com/search/">
                    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" required placeholder="Start Learning...">
                    <input type="submit" value="" class="searchbtn1">
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: What result do you want to achieve?

Comment: same as iphone @SergeyDenisov

Comment: http://mobt.me/BK8T as here

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: yes trying to implement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should read [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) of the framework you're using:

> **Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint**
>
> The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than `@grid-float-breakpoint`, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least `@grid-float-breakpoint` in width. Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is `768px` (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).

Your code works well, but using default variable value.

If you want collapsed `navbar` (and other components maybe too) on `768px`, you should override your [variables.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L330) file with a larger value, for example with [@screen-md-min](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L303) (`992px`):

```
@grid-float-breakpoint: @screen-md-min;
```

For more information about Bootstrap variables overriding see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350779/bootstrap-variable-overriding-with-less).